# EPiServer schedule job not running automatically

Tags: scheduler, episerver, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2

I am working on EPiserver CMS6. My schedule jobs are not running automatically. When I tried to run manually they work properly. 
Is there any configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the database, in the table tblScheduledItem. Sometimes a job "hangs" and prevents other jobs from starting. Look for a "1" in the column IsRunning, and then check if LastExec is a while ago. I would then set the IsRunning to 0. Wait a minute (or restart the EPiServer Scheduler service) and see if the jobs start running again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the EPiServer Scheduler service is running. If not, you should be able to install it using the EPiServer Deployment Center.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I install it via Episerver deployment center?

Answer (score 0):

If your tblScheduledItem is missing the column SecondsAfterLastPing you should apply this hotfix:

http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Shahid-Nawaz/Dates/2012/1/General-Hotfix-CMS-6-R2/

Otherwise all scheduling can stop completely and never recover.